# Mobile users unable to access Facebook custom page tab

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-tabs

I have a tab on my Facebook page (one of those static HTML: iFrame apps). There are no problems accessing it from a PC, however when I try accessing the tab from a mobile device it doesn't appear.

Is there some way I can either create a tab accessible on mobile devices, or just redirect them to an external domain?

Comment: @luschn can yo explain this answer elaboratly

Comment: page tabs are not available on mobile, redirection is also not possible. you would need to use the EXTERNAL link to check for mobile/desktop, and redirect to the page tab on desktop if needed.

Comment: @luschn there is any alternative solution for the my business page display as the mobile tab

Comment: nope, there is not.